# bcmwl-kernel-source broken on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, broadcom, macbook-air

Similar to [bcmwl-kernel-source broken on kernel: 5.8.0-7630-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305645/bcmwl-kernel-source-broken-on-kernel-5-8-0-7630-generic) except I'm using a standard kernel - WiFi worked without issues on my MacBook Air (2013) right until I pulled in the latest 20.04.2 update which included the `5.8.0-34-generic` kernel, and booting back into `5.4.0-59-generic` afterwards does not solve the issue. Anyway, details are as follows; any help would be much appreciated.

#### `lspci -vnn | grep Network`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0117]
```

#### `ip link show`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:49:bc:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:49:bc:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: bnep0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:38:35:4a:43:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

As can be seen, there's no wireless interface.

#### `sudo lshw -class network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:b0600000-b0607fff memory:b0400000-b05fffff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: virbr0
       serial: 52:54:00:49:bc:05
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: bnep0
       serial: 84:38:35:4a:43:4b
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.124 multicast=yes
  *-network:2 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:49:bc:05
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

### Steps I took to try to resolve the issue

I followed [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) and did the following:

1. `lspci -nn -d 14e4:` reveals that the PCI.ID is 14e4:43a0 (rev 03) so I should (re)install `bcmwl-kernel-source`
2. `sudo apt purge -y bcmwl-kernel-source`
3. `sudo apt autoremove`
4. `sudo apt update`
5. `sudo update-pciids`
6. `sudo apt-get install -y bcmwl-kernel-source`

... followed by a reboot.

I did all the steps (except the first one) with both the `5.8.0-34-generic` and `5.4.0-59-generic` kernels and the outputs for the last command are as follows:

#### `5.8.0-34-generic`

STDOUT:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dkms
Suggested packages:
  menu
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcmwl-kernel-source dkms
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,611 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,364 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 204877 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.8.1-5ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.8.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up dkms (2.8.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-34-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.8.0-34-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
```

STDERR:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

#### `5.4.0-59-generic`

STDOUT:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dkms
Suggested packages:
  menu
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcmwl-kernel-source dkms
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,611 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,364 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 204877 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.8.1-5ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.8.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up dkms (2.8.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-59-generic 5.8.0-34-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-59-generic
This system doesn't support Secure Boot
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

wl.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-59-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
Building initial module for 5.8.0-34-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
```

STDERR:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In both cases, the output suggests looking at `/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log` which shows:

```
DKMS make.log for bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom for kernel 5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Thursday, January 07, 2021 PM01:19:23 CST
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  AR      /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/built-in.a
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_iw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.o
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_attach’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:593:20: error: implicit declaration of function ‘ioremap_nocache’; did you mean ‘ioremap_cache’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  593 |  if ((wl->regsva = ioremap_nocache(dev->base_addr, PCI_BAR0_WINSZ)) == NULL) {
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    ioremap_cache
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:593:18: warning: assignment to ‘void *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  593 |  if ((wl->regsva = ioremap_nocache(dev->base_addr, PCI_BAR0_WINSZ)) == NULL) {
      |                  ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_pci_probe’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:780:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  780 |  if ((val & 0x0000ff00) != 0)
      |  ^~
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:782:3: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
  782 |   bar1_size = pci_resource_len(pdev, 2);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:783:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  783 |   bar1_addr = (uchar *)ioremap_nocache(pci_resource_start(pdev, 2),
      |               ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_reg_proc_entry’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3376:58: error: passing argument 4 of ‘proc_create_data’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 3376 |  if ((wl->proc_entry = proc_create_data(tmp, 0644, NULL, &wl_fops, wl)) == NULL) {
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~
      |                                                          |
      |                                                          const struct file_operations *
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:38:
./include/linux/proc_fs.h:102:31: note: expected ‘const struct proc_ops *’ but argument is of type ‘const struct file_operations *’
  102 | extern struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create_data(const char *, umode_t,
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.c: In function ‘osl_reg_map’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.c:949:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘ioremap_nocache’; did you mean ‘ioremap_cache’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  949 |  return (ioremap_nocache((unsigned long)pa, (unsigned long)size));
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |          ioremap_cache
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.c:949:10: warning: returning ‘int’ from a function with return type ‘void *’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  949 |  return (ioremap_nocache((unsigned long)pa, (unsigned long)size));
      |         ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:40:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c: In function ‘wl_set_auth_type’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.h:52:5: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
   52 |  if (wl_dbg_level & WL_DBG_DBG) {   \
      |     ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:816:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘WL_DBG’
  816 |   WL_DBG(("network eap\n"));
      |   ^~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:817:2: note: here
  817 |  default:
      |  ^~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:288: /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:288: /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1780: /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic'
```

---

In the meantime, my Bluetooth is working so I am connecting to the Internet by Bluetooth tethering with my Android device. But it's very much a temporary solution and I would not like to rely on it for the long run.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The reason is obvious. Almost every time Canonical rolls out a HWE kernel, they forget to upgrade `bcmwl-kernel-source` in the repos.

You have two solutions (**use one or the other, it makes no sense to use both**):

1. Install `bcmwl-kernel-source` from `groovy` repos. You can find it e.g. here. http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb It will compile with the 5.8 kernel.

Download the deb and install it by

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb
```

2. Remove all 5.8 kernel packages using these commands:

   ```
    sudo apt remove linux-{image,modules,modules-extra,headers}-5.8.0-36-generic linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-36
    sudo apt install linux-generic
   ```

Make sure that the `linux-generic` meta package is installed.

It is recommended to boot with the 5.4 kernel before you remove the 5.8.

The second solution will keep the 5.4 major kernel version with normal security upgrades.

Comment: Thanks, I followed the second solution you suggested and unheld kernel updates. As for the first solution, I don't need such a new kernel as long as everything works for me and my system is secure.

Comment: I think adding the hwe meta was also a mistake by someone. They never came before till xx.04.2 releases. That will cause trouble for many people. But I am usng Ubuntu for a long time and expect some mess every beginning of an odd year ;-)

Comment: Install `synaptic` and remove all linux-image... and linux-headers... packages version 5.8 and also those meta packages.

Comment: Thank you!  Option 1 worked a treat for me!

Comment: Could you also add a link to the upstream bug? While this is a great workaround, the proper fix needs to come from Canonical. Anyone affected by it should go to the bug report and mark that it affects them so it can get more attention: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1910555

Answer (score 4):

I managed to restore WiFi with kernel `5.4.0-59-generic` as follows:

1. Purge all packages related to kernel `5.8.0-34-generic`: `sudo apt purge linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic linux-image-unsigned-5.8.0-34-generic linux-modules-5.8.0-34-generic linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic`
2. Purge the Broadcom WiFi driver: `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`
3. Remove redundant packages: `sudo apt autoremove`
4. Put the `5.4.0-59-generic` kernel on hold: `sudo apt-mark hold 5.4.0-59-generic`
5. Update package metadata: `sudo apt update`
6. Re-install the driver: `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`

Since the `5.8.0-34-generic` kernel is gone, the driver is compiled only for the `5.4.0-59-generic` kernel which succeeds as expected. Reboot, and WiFi is restored.

Hopefully I can unhold the kernel and receive kernel updates as usual once this is sorted out.

Comment: It is not a good idea to put the `5.4.0-59-generic` on hold. It won't get updates. If you removed `linux-generic-hwe-20.04`, `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04` you'll never get the 5.8 again. But the 5.4 will get updates normally, e.g. to `5.4.0-60`.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, you can use the ubuntu 20.10 version of the package and it works just fine, at its [origin repo](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.10/ubuntu-restricted-amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb.html)

Answer (score 2):

Found an alternative solution while tracing errors in bcmwl-kernel-source.

See [this question on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416180/ubuntu-no-wifi-adapter-found)

I tried the solution listed in the thread, which involves purging the `bcmwl-kernel-source` and installing `broadcom-sta` and it works for me in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with the Linux 5.8.0-36 headers installed.

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-source broadcom-sta-dkms broadcom-sta-common
```

Comment: `broadcom-sta-dkms` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

**Broadcom Wifi crashed after Ubuntu 20.04 LTS kernel update 8.15.34 ~ 36**

How to know kernel version?

```
uname -r
```

How to know your crashed adapter?

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

You will see the crashed adapter with the following title:

**-network UNCLAIMED*

How to fix:

**SOLUTION 1**

Install the following device driver:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb

**ALTERNATIVE**

If not worked, try the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

**ALTERNATIVE**
Reinstall the kernel

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

After that try the above solutions again.

Comment: worked 100%. I tried the installation of deb package and driver worked and wifi also works 100% now and i did not have to downgrade to 5.4 version. My laptop is a little mini Lenovo ideapad S10-3 Model.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, starting with an 'apt' upgrade about three weeks ago.  It appears that a fix has now been made available in the Ubuntu repositories.  After today's upgrade, my Broadcom wireless interface is back and operational.  The upgrade included this package:

bcmwl-kernel-source  6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.1

Answer (score 0):

This issue should already be fixed as per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1872908

Update your system and the fix should be applied, e.g.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

If you've already installed a newer version of `bcmwl-kernel-source` to work around this issue as some of the other answers suggest, you may want to uninstall it and install the proper version, e.g.

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

**Note** that if you're running the 5.8 kernel because you installed the HWE (`linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04`), then you will probably also have the 5.11 kernel installed as well. Thankfully the issue has been fixed for 5.11 as well.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to broken wifi (short of using an ethernet cable to your wifi router box) is to give your machine internet from your phone ... for android 12 (although similar for other releases and for iphone) is connect your computer to your phone using a USB cable then on your phone goto Settings -> Network & Internet -> Hotspot & tethering -> USB tethering and turn on this setting

This will work when your phone has either a data plan or is itself on wifi

I need to do this when for testing purposes I install the mainline kernel which is typically several releases newer than the latest Ubuntu release and broadcom wireless drivers are not ready yet