# How do I install `bcmwl-kernel-source` with dpkg

Tags: drivers, wireless, software-installation, kernel, dpkg

Apparently, Canonical rolled out a HWE kernel and forget to upgrade `bcmwl-kernel-source` in the repos. This has caused my wifi adapter to go missing from my computer.

[This solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305699/bcmwl-kernel-source-broken-on-kernel-5-8-0-34-generic) recommends the following:

> Install bcmwl-kernel-source from eoan repos. You can find it e.g. here. http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb It will compile with the 5.8 kernel.

My implementation of these instructions looks like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt autoremove
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

But it doesn't work and I get an error:

```
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: 
'/var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 
5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
...
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log
for more information.
```

I imagine I'm not installing `bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb` in the correct manner. How do I do it right?

Comment: Please consult the log as was suggested: `cat /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log` What does it say the error was?

Comment: I made a mistake with `eoan`. After the holidays I thought that eoan was 20.10 for some reason :-)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we see, bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu**4** doesn't compile correctly for your system. On my system, using the exact same kernel version, bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu**7** installs correctly. I therefore suggest:

```
mkdir bcmwl && cd bcmwl
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Is there any improvement?

Comment: That worked! Is there a proper way to choose the `bcmwl-*-0ubuntuX` file? How would I choose `X`? Or is choosing `X` simply a matter of trial and error?

Comment: Although there may be some other canonical method, I simply ran: `lsb_release -c` and then matched the codename here: https://packages.ubuntu.com and search for *bcmwl*. Next I noted X. It is not perfectly clear that this will be successful in each and every setting, especially the problematic HWE kernel versions, but, in this case, it worked.