# Ubuntu Broadcam driver doesn't work

Tags: networking, 20.04

Hi I went to Additional drivers because I want to select the wifi driver but when I select the wifi card I give me the following errorn

[image]

and I don't how this happen I just open my pc and the wifi disappear

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `uname -r` and: `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source | grep Version`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi Doesn't Show up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306319/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-doesnt-show-up)

Comment: @chili555 They did already. It is what we are thinking ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 I like this answer, too! https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305988/how-do-i-install-bcmwl-kernel-source-with-dpkg

Comment: @chili555 I like it too and upvoted ;-)