# Error in removal of 5.8.0-34-generic kernel

Tags: wireless, kernel

My wifi adapter stopped working suddenly and after some research I found out it was due to a recent kernel update.

I was trying to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1305816/736513) solution to fix the issue but after step 1:

> Purge all packages related to kernel 5.8.0-34-generic:
> `sudo apt purge linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic linux-image-unsigned-5.8.0-34-generic linux-modules-5.8.0-34-generic linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic`

I am getting the following error:

```
(Reading database ... 266336 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic (5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2) ...
E: Aborting removal of the running kernel
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
E: Aborting removal of the running kernel
```

You are trying to remove the kernel you are currently running. Please boot a different kernel (if you don't get the GRUB menu on boot, press Shift or the arrow keys) and remove the kernel you want. You can check your running kernel with `uname -r`