# Cant install bcwml-kernel-source in kernel 5.8.0

Tags: drivers, 20.04, broadcom

The drivers for my Broadcom WiFi card are playing monkey tricks again. Apparently when I try to re-install the drivers, I get an error due to bcwml-kernel-source being missing, but when I try to install it, I get this:

```sh
➜ sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Removing old bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
 
------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-34-generic 5.8.0-36-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.8.0-34-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix this problem?

UPDATE:

I tried to do like it says in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305699/bcmwl-kernel-source-broken-on-kernel-5-8-0-34-generic) but it also did not work.

```
➜ sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb 
dpkg: warning: downgrading bcmwl-kernel-source from 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5 to 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4
(Reading database ... 300024 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) over (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-34-generic 5.8.0-36-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.8.0-34-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--install):
 installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: That solution is for 19.10, no? I am in 20.04. I tried it anyway, and it didnt help

Comment: That solution is for 20.04.

Comment: @Pilot6 Well, the solution propesed in that question was to use the package `0ubuntu4`, and that didn't work for me. I just saw that 5 hours ago you edited the answer to include the correct version that I posted in my answer.

Comment: `eoan` and `groovy` mixed up in my mind. So I took a wrong link initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After browsing the list of drivers, I took the latest one. In my case `0ubuntu7`. That one did the trick!

```
wget http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271%2Bbdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb
```