# No Wifi Similar to: bcmwl-kernel-source broken on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic

Tags: drivers, package-management, kernel, broadcom

Similar to the post [bcmwl-kernel-source broken on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305699/bcmwl-kernel-source-broken-on-kernel-5-8-0-34-generic), but I can't seem to get any of the proposed work around solutions to work.

I'm on a Macbook Pro 2012 model. My usual solution when the wifi has issues is to just run:

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

```
matthew@matthew-MacBookPro:~/Downloads$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 57 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Removing old bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom
Kernel:  5.4.0-59-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

wl.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-59-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
It is likely that 5.8.0-34-generic belongs to a chroot's host
Building for 5.4.0-42-generic, 5.4.0-52-generic, 5.4.0-53-generic, 5.4.0-54-generic, 5.4.0-56-generic, 5.4.0-58-generic, 5.4.0-59-generic and 5.8.0-36-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for kernel 5.4.0-42-generic was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Module build for kernel 5.4.0-52-generic was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Module build for kernel 5.4.0-53-generic was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Module build for kernel 5.4.0-54-generic was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Module build for kernel 5.4.0-56-generic was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Module build for kernel 5.4.0-58-generic was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Building initial module for 5.4.0-59-generic
This system doesn't support Secure Boot
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

wl.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-59-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
Building initial module for 5.8.0-36-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm having no luck this time. I tried many of the solutions posted in response to Donald Sebastian's question, but none of the solutions seems to be working.

I tried installing the bcwml-kernel-source file from here (http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ) manually through the GUI installer, but I get this error:

Unable to install bcmwl-kernel-source:
Error while installing package: Installed bcmwl-kernel-source package scrip subprocess returned error exit status 10.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Bot with the 5.4 kernel and either remove the 5.8, or install the driver from 20.10 repos.

Comment: Installing the driver from here worked for me: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.10/ubuntu-restricted-amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb.html  Thanks!