# Wireless adapter not showing up anymore

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom

Since yesterday my pcie wireless adapter doesn't show up anymore in the drop down menu (upper right corner of the screen) or in any other menu as far as I saw. It's an Asus PCE-AC68 and it's using a Broadcom BCM4360 driver.

I tried a solution I found on this website ( [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) ) but it threw a dpgk error during the reinstalling another solution I tried (https://suryanshpradhan.wordpress.com/2020/01/17/how-to-fix-broadcom-bcm43142-wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04-3-lts/ )  didn't work since when I tried  sudo modprobe -rv bcma wl or  sudo rmmod bcma wl I got permission denied, I tried to remove bcma but I couldn't since it was in use, I also tried to cancel everything with the name bcmwl-kernel-source but when I tried to install the package again I got an error, I reinstalled a fresh Ubuntu 20.10 (before I had 20.04) erasing everything from the SSD but not even this fixed the issue.

I'm sure the wireless adapter works as I use it on Win 10.

Edit: I've just run the command lshw -C network and the broadcom network results UNCLAIMED

Edit 2: now that I found the network was unclaimed I was able to find a possible solution related to secure boot and by going inside the BIOS changing secure boot from Windows to Other OS solved my issue. Strange it worked till yesterday and suddenly stopped though

Edit 3: the secure boot solution worked for the 20.10 but not for the 20.04, to fix the issue on Ubuntu 20.04 I followed the six steps here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1907557

Comment: Is it a USB wireless adapter that you are calling "antenna"? Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Pilot6 I changed the term antenna with wireless adapter as it was confusing I also manage to find some solutions which I added to my post, I found the first solution by researching using the world wireless adapter instead of antenna. Thanks for giving me the right word

Comment: There is a problem with Broadcom drivers on 20.04. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305699/bcmwl-kernel-source-broken-on-kernel-5-8-0-34-generic/1305819#1305819

Comment: yes i faced the same and struggling to solve this!