# Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi Doesn't Show up

Tags: networking, 20.04

Hi All I've restarted my pc but when I check my connection at the top right corner I no longer can see the wifi icon the problem at start with that the cursor of my mouse doesn't want to move when I use the touch pad so I restarted my pc then that's what happen

[This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjq23.png)

the wifi section in setting has also gone

[Setting picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjq23.png)

I don't know what to do I tried to restart my pc one more time but no use the problem still occurer

when I run `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; uname -r`

it give me the following output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
5.8.0-36-generic
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; uname -r` terminal command.

Comment: I have added the output for the command " lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; uname -r "

Comment: This is a known issue with the new kernel.

Comment: the other answer on the question   suggest [bcmwl-kernel-source broken on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic ](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305699/bcmwl-kernel-source-broken-on-kernel-5-8-0-34-generic#1305819) that  remove the following package   `linux-generic-hwe-20.04
 linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04`         but it give me that error `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`

Comment: The easiest is the first option. Download the deb and install in using `dpkg -i bcmwl....`.