# WiFi connection keeps failing on BCM4313 [14e4:4727 rev 01]

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I'm a Linux noob and I can't get my WiFi BACK to work properly.
THE PROBLEM: Around a week ago, the WiFi on my notebook started to fail, so, as the problem persisted, I've just wiped it with a fresh UBUNTU 20.04.1 LTS, but the problem persists: Internet connection works for a while, but navigation periodically stops working for around 1 minute, then gets back to normal.

NOTES:

- The problem happens exclusively on that machine.
- The problem doesn't occur when I plug in a USB WiFi adapter.
- Anything I "ping" to responds without packet loss, during the problem, at the same time I can't access them though the web browsers (Firefox and Chrome).
- Channels are fixed to 20MHz on the router.

DATA I'VE COLLECTED: sudo lspci -v

```
12:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Inspiron M5010 / XPS 8300
Physical Slot: 0-1
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at fbc00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-9d-ff-ff-c3-1c-65
Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
Kernel modules: bcma
```

rfkill

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
1 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
```

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:
-1- Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) thread.

```
sudo apt install linux-firmware
sudo reboot
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43    
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo reboot
```

-2- By impulse
I tried to use the "Software & Updates > Additional Drivers" to install the "Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)"; Not only the problem persisted, but also I couldn't install anything from the Ubuntu Software application until I reinstalled the OS again, as an error message was shown.

-3- By despair
Disabled IPV6; No difference.

I'd really thank If someone can help me to solve that problem.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305699/bcmwl-kernel-source-broken-on-kernel-5-8-0-34-generic/1305819#1305819

Comment: Just did it, tried the "solution 1", yet the problem persists... :/
One thing I noticed: "lspci -v" now returns:
ll

Kernel driver in use: wl
// Kernel modules: bcma, wl

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED
I managed to solve the problem by setting my router on channel 11 (It was on ch3/automatic), I tried it because I decided to install WIN10 as after all I tried, I thought the problem would not be exclusively dependant on my laptop's software (even thou everything I had to the moment pointed to that), so, as the problem persisted on win10, I started to try anything that came to mind, from disassembling the laptop to clean the wifi adapter socket to test other configurations on my router.
I have no idea on why does that problem occurs the way it occurs and exclusively with my laptop.

Thanks everyone for trying to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in terminal`sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` and then try this command `sudo service network-manager restart`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Did this worked? @Kalidio Dzk

Comment: the first line didn't show any sponse, but the second one wrote "network: unrecognized service", but thank U anyway :]

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in second command I have made it correct now you can try it.Yeah and I know that second command didn't give any response but it works.@KalidioDzk

Comment: Oh, I see... Now I noticed the wifi icon actually disconnected and reconnected. I'll be testing and tomorrow, I'll come back here to tell if it worked. Thanks again :]

Comment: Sadly, the problem persists :/