# bcmwl-kernel-source broken Manual fix, Breaks in the future?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, kernel, updates, broadcom

I had the problem, that the bcmwl-kernel-source broke after updating my upbuntu to the kernel 5.8.0-36-generic #40~20.04.1-Ubuntu. Same as the Question [bcmwl-kernel-source-broken-on-kernel-5-8-0-34-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305699/bcmwl-kernel-source-broken-on-kernel-5-8-0-34-generic).

The fix from the answer worked for me. Thanks to [Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/users/167850/pilot6).

*Answer*
Install bcmwl-kernel-source from groovy repos. You can find it e.g. here. http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb It will compile with the 5.8 kernel.

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb
```

**Question**
Now does the WIFI kernel break again with the next Kernel update?
Do i need to manual install the kernel source on every update again?

Or is it somehow possible to prevent such breaks? Since I'm using the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I didn't expected such error's.

Comment: Does that driver install a DKMS driver?  The way to check is run `dkms status` from a command line.  If you see that driver in the list then when the next kernel update comes it will install into the new kernel.  If not, you will have to compile it against the kernel again until they fix it.

Answer (score 1):

No, the driver won't break on kernel upgrades any more. It is a `dkms` driver. It will build with new kernels automatically.

So unless the system is upgraded to some new major kernel version, the driver should work. But we all hope that Canonical will upgrade the driver properly in the repos next time.