# Broadcom BCM43xxxx wireless device wifi had disappeared after updating/upgrading (January 2021)

Tags: wireless

!
many other threads like this one

[bcmwl-kernel-source broken on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305699/bcmwl-kernel-source-broken-on-kernel-5-8-0-34-generic)

didn't solve my issue with Broadcome wifi disappeared after updates.
!

Here is a very straightforward decision.

My name is Vladimir and I have found the decision that worked for my case.
So, on my Ubuntu 20.04 on HP 250G laptop with Broadcom BCM43xxxx wireless device wifi had disappeared after updating/upgrading (January 2021).
After 3 days of searches and dozens of errors gotten, I have found this cure:

```
apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
apt-get install broadcom-sta-source
apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
apt-get install broadcom-sta-common
```

Thanks to joaorami (joaomppr) from
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1878045

Comment: This is not a question. The duplicate has this solution already https://askubuntu.com/a/1306588/167850 Why do you keep  posting this/

Comment: Hi. I just wanted to prevent people from reading to long threads trying to find this decision. Any way many thanks for what you do here at askubuntu.

Comment: This is a question and answer site. This is not a forum with threads. You posted this as a question. It makes no sense. And other solutions work perfectly too.

Comment: Please read https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. May I ask you for the way you as admin manage to take decisions on duplicated questions so quickly? This is amasing.

Comment: I am not an admin. I have a golden tag badge on wireless questions.

Comment: I see. Good to you then. I'm a regular user of UBUNTU and find this operating system very robust and cool in spite of some issues arising from time to time.