# WIFI driver isues. Wifi and boot up lag Ubunti 20.04 recent update

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, hp, broadcom

I have been using 20.04 for a few week. I have dabbled with Ubuntu trying to make it my go to operating system - I have used command line a little, i am by no means well versed in it's use and can only do very basic operations so please keep any response simple.

20.04 was working ok up until the most recent update 4 days ago (apx), however, since the latest update I am having problem with WIFI. There is no WIFI button in the OS. The only network settings available are Ethernet wired and USB tether, when I connect my Samsung s8 Active through USB type C.

WIFI card is a Broadcom 802.21 CARD (the machine is old, (it's a HP Pro Book 6460b);
driver is :- Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA source bcmwl-kernel-source(propriety).
(found in software & update in the (gnome gui window)

**I tried updating & upgrading.

**I saw a tutorial mentioning driver validation failure so i tried

```
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

which returned

`sudo mokutil --disable-validation command not found`

```
**sudo lshw -C network

returned

  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: a0:b3:cc:28:2e:3c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:31 memory:d4700000-d471ffff memory:d472a000-d472afff ioport:4060(size=32)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:24:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d4400000-d4403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:1.2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: fa:18:b5:c7:6a:cd
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.150 link=yes multicast=yes
mike@mike-HP-ProBook-6460b:~$ ^C
mike@mike-HP-ProBook-6460b:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: a0:b3:cc:28:2e:3c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:31 memory:d4700000-d471ffff memory:d472a000-d472afff ioport:4060(size=32)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:24:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d4400000-d4403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:1.2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: fa:18:b5:c7:6a:cd
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.150 link=yes multicast=yes
```

regarding the display I have not even started trouble shooting that yet - there is a ton on lag, the OS doesn't crash but the screen remains black and back lit then I must ctrl + alt del to switch into the GUI.

Thank in advance -

N.B

```
mike@mike-HP-ProBook-6460b:~$ sudo rfkill list all
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
mike@mike-HP-ProBook-6460b:~$ sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source | grep Status
Status: install ok installed
mike@mike-HP-ProBook-6460b:~$ dmesg | grep wl
[    0.000000] DMI: Hewlett-Packard HP ProBook 6460b/161D, BIOS 68SCE Ver. F.67 02/13/2018
mike@mike-HP-ProBook-6460b:~$
```

Comment: so sorry for the formatting im super new, this is my first post. if I'm have not followed protocol or etiquette please say nicely hehehe no trolling :)

Comment: It is pretty unreadable.

Comment: `uname -r` copy and paste this on your terminal, and this will give the Linux kernel version. If it is `5.8.0-38-generic` then https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305699/bcmwl-kernel-source-broken-on-kernel-5-8-0-34-generic this link will provide you with the solution. It worked for me. The top answer worked for me.