# Wifi disabled, adapter 'Unclaimed' (dual boot Ubuntu 20.04.2/Windows 10)

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, 20.04, atheros

*Problem fixed, see my own answer below.

I am asking for help regarding my Wifi adapter, which used to work fine until last restart. It's still working if I boot from a Live Ubuntu drive or on Windows. I did not mess with the drivers or kernel. *This could have happened after a Windows 10 update (dual boot). The wifi adapter is an internal PCIe Qualcomm Atheros AR938x.

In Windows 10: I disabled fast startup, updated drivers and ticked off 'Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power' in Device Manager

In the BIOS: I updated to the latest version and disabled most security settings

Some commands I ran in Ubuntu:

sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network NON-RÉCLAMÉ     
       description: Network controller
       produit: AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
       fabricant: Qualcomm Atheros
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 01
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration : latency=0
       ressources : mémoire:ef100000-ef11ffff mémoire:ef120000-ef12ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       fabricant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 1f.6
       information bus: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       nom logique: enp0s31f6
       version: 31
       numéro de série: 1c:1b:0d:1c:f8:ad
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 32 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration : autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.2-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       ressources : irq:131 mémoire:ef200000-ef21ffff
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f1)
00:1b.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #19 (rev f1)
00:1b.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #20 (rev f1)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 04)
08:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

lspci -nnk

```
[...]
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [8086:15b8] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
[...]
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0030] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:3112]
```

sudo lspci -v

```
[...]
08:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at ef100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Expansion ROM at ef120000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [300] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
```

lspci -vvnn | grep Network

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0030] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:3112]
```

lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network | grep Kernel

```
(nothing)

sudo modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-43-generic

sudo modprobe -r ath9k
modprobe: FATAL: Module ath9k not found.

sudo modprobe -r ath5k
modprobe: FATAL: Module ath5k not found.

sudo modprobe -r ath_pci
modprobe: FATAL: Module ath_pci not found.
```

Any pointers are welcome! Ubuntu also won't acknowledge my cellphone as a USB tether so I am pretty much without any network unless I boot on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

So my wireless drivers disappeared somehow. I fixed my problem installing the following packages using dpkg :

linux-modules-5.8.0-43-generic_5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1_amd64.deb
linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-43-generic_5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1_amd64.deb
bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb
([this answer helped](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305699/bcmwl-kernel-source-broken-on-kernel-5-8-0-34-generic))

I realized that apt was generating an error telling me that 'linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-34-generic' depends on 'linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic' which is not installed. Once I got network back, running sudo apt --fix-broken install took care of it. Could this be related to what caused my problem?

Anyway, problem fixed